# Detecting users location and current time using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way to detect the users location (country and city) and their current time using javascript.

for the current time i managed to find this:

```
<script language="javascript">
ourDate = new Date();
document.write("The time and date at your computer's location is: "
+ ourDate.toLocaleString()
+ ".<br/>");
document.write("The time zone offset between local time and GMT is "
+ ourDate.getTimezoneOffset()
+ " minutes.<br/>");
document.write("The time and date (GMT) is: "
+ ourDate.toGMTString()
+ ".<br/>");
</script>
```

but the seconds are not ticking and it wont update until the page is re-loaded!

is there an easy way to achieve this?

just need something like this:

Your location is: XXXXXXXXXX and your time is: xxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

To get the clock to update, you will have to use a timer with `setInterval`.

To get the location, there are API's to get the location, then you will have to de-geocode the location. Not all browsers support it and it can't be done with what is built in.